# Ionic AngularFire Realtime Database - Change Default UID of pushed entry

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, nosql, angularfire

I am working on an Ionic app that, among other things, should assign a corresponding database entry with a key that *is the same* as the user's generated UID they get upon registration. Also important to note is that the users themselves *cannot* create accounts - only the single administrator can.

[image: Image of what I want to change]

Here's my current code.

```
addUserToDb(username: string, email: string, password: string) {
    this.firebaseAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(data => {
    var newId = data.user.uid; // Gets UID of new user.
    const usersRef = this.db.list('users'); // Gets list to be pushed to
    let keyToChange = usersRef.push(
    {
        admin: false,
        identifier: data.user.email,
        username: username,
    }).key; // Does the push AND gets the key for the newly added entry
    console.log(`User's old id is ` + keyToChange + " | User's new id will be " + newId);
    var userToUpdate = this.db.object('users/' + keyToChange); // Gets entry to be edited
    userToUpdate.update({[keyToChange]: newId}); // <- WHAT DO I DO HERE?
    console.log('Success!', username);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    username: null;
    email: null;
    password: null;
    console.log('Something went wrong:', err.message);
  });    
}
```

Right now, the code causes this result:

[image: What I actually get]

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using 'push' which generates an ID, you can use 'set' with the ID that you want

```
 this.db.object(`users/${newId}`).set({
    admin: false,
    identifier: data.user.email,
    username: username,
 });
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a ton!